# UITableViewCellStyleValue2 - Adjust the width?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have cells that use the UITableViewCellStyleValue2 style.  The problem is that the width of the label area is too small.  Is it possible to specify the width for the labels?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, but you could place your own labels as subviews of a stock table view cell, with the requisite dimensions.